# adding multiple values to an array or object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, structure

i like to have array or object like:

```
[0]
   text:"first"
   id: 1
[1]
   text:"second"
   id: 2
[2]
   text:"third"
   id: 3
```

getting myself:

```
1: first
2: 1
3: second
4: 2
5: third
6: 3
```

here is my **javascript** with implementation for the **array** at the moment:

```
 var numberOfQuestions = questionaireResult.numberOfQuestions;
                var i;
                var j;
                var result = [];

                for (i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
                    debugger;
                    var question = questionaireResult.questions[i].text;
                    var questionID = questionaireResult.questions[i].id;


                    for (j = 0; j < questionaireResult.questions[i].answers.length; j++) {

                        var text = questionaireResult.questions[i].answers[j].text;
                        var id = questionaireResult.questions[i].answers[j].id;
                        result.push(text, id);
                    }
}
```

please help to get a structured array or object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Push an object containing your data to the array instead:

```
result.push({text: text, id: id});
```

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs: In the next version of JavaScript (ECMAScript6), it'll be even more concise: `result.push({text, id});` (that will be functionally identical to the above; basically it just figures out the name of the property from the name of the variable). But we don't have ES6 yet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to store all answers into a single array, you could use `concat` to get the expected result and reduce the amount of code at the same time :

```
var questions = questionaireResult.questions,
    result = [],
    l = questions.length,
    i = 0;

for (; i < l; i++) {
    result = result.concat(
        questions[i].answers
    );
}
```

Here is how `concat` works ([mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)) :

```
var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [4, 5, 6];
a.concat(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```